# Why do I need to install packages that are "automatically installed with Anaconda"?

Tags: anaconda

The Anaconda website states that [Over 150 packages are automatically installed with Anaconda.](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/#packages-available-in-anaconda) Of which I assume it is referring to the [packages](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs) with a check mark under "In Installer".

However, it appears that not all packages that are "In Installer" are actually installed

e.g. sympy is stated as "In Installer" however, when I create an environment and firing up python, `import sympy` gives `No module named 'sympy'` and I have to run `conda install sympy` to install it

My question is, **how do I interpret the meaning of "automatically installed with Anaconda" and "In Installer"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default packages (installed via the installer) are present in the root environment. If you want to have those packages in a newly created environment, simply [clone](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#clone-an-environment) the environment containing those packages:

```
(root) ~/condaexpts$ conda create -yn sympyenv --clone root
Source:      /home/ubuntu/condaexpts/m2
Destination: /home/ubuntu/condaexpts/m2/envs/sympyenv
The following packages cannot be cloned out of the root environment:
 - conda-4.3.9-py27_0
 - conda-env-2.6.0-0
Packages: 26
Files: 0
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > source activate sympyenv
#
# To deactivate this environment, use:
# > source deactivate sympyenv
#

(root) ~/condaexpts$ source activate sympyenv
(sympyenv) ubuntu@gitlab:~/condaexpts$ python
Python 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.__version__
'1.0'
>>>
```